# SSIS Rows Per Batch Expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

is it possible to set "Rows Per Batch" and "Maximum Insert Commit Size" via expressions? i.e. so that they can be driven by a config table? I know the buffer sizes can, but I couldn't spot anything for these two properties.

Comment: Please explain what it is you're trying to achieve then perhaps we can come up with options

Comment: I want to control this along with an array of other settings via a config table.

So in summary:
Master package gets all child package information and calls packages one by one or in parallel
Each package "late binds" with such information as rows per batch, buffer sizes
If a data flow is poorly performing, values in the config table could be tweaked via a simple update to the config table. Meaning lower risk deployments and change requests

Comment: Plus what I consider good design - things are not hard coded in the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `Rows Per Batch` and `Maximum Insert Commit Size` properties cannot be set via expressions.

The OLEDB Destination properties cannot be set via expressions except the table name it can be read from a variable.

The properties that you can set via expressions are the Data Flow Task properties, or sometimes there are some data flow component properties that can be set via expressions like the XML Source file path.

The `DefaultBufferSize` and `DefaultBufferMaxRows` properties that you mentioned are related to Data Flow. But if you open the expression form of the data flow task you will not see any of the `OLEDB Destination` properties.

Comment: That's what I expected. Frustrating given some of the performance elements are exposed, whereas these two aren't.  Thanks anyway